# Excel: Spill out all matching rows

Tags: excel, spill-range

For an Excel documenten I am fitlering the data to create a "view". I got several rows of data containing the following data

| type | sender | duration | price |

In my view I want the following columns:

| sender | duration | price |

---

Type = data / call

Sender = phone number (several different)

Duration = time in seconds

Price = is total price for seconds

---

In the view I want the unique list of `phone numbers` if `type` is `data`, then I want the total `duration` and total `price`. The latter of these is done using `SUMIFS`

---

I know that there's an option by filtering by hand. But I assume you already found that I want this in code.

I already tried `XLOOKUP` but this only returns one result as cell reference. `XMATCH` isn't the holy grail either.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `=UNIQUE(FILTER(...))` I'd hoped that `XLOOKUP` and `XMATCH` were there to help with this.

Feel free to feedback if you have a better formula, please!

Comment: And did you also figure out how to return only the columns of interest?